# shiny datatable paging not working in shinydashboard

Tags: datatable, shiny, shinydashboard

when using [shinydashboard library](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html) it seems to override the datatable (DT) css so that datatable paging and search boxes are not available. even

```
options = list(paging = TRUE)
```

does not render paged tables as it should.

any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with shinydashboard. Have you included the argument `dom` in your call to datatable:

```
DT::datatable(mydf, options=list(dom='ftp')))
```

f for filtering, t for the table, p for paging.

Comment: I get Warning: Error in DT::datatable: unused argument (dom = "ftp"), this argument is not listed in the DT::datatable object

Comment: I still have DT 0.10, it seems on Dec 19, 2019 version 0.11 was released. Do I have to upgrade?

Comment: Sorry about that. it's in options